# Javascript issue when iframe reloads with using parent javascript.

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a parent and child iframe where the calls to the parent javascript file is working fine till the iframe is refresh. The moment I reload the iframe the parent javascript goes away. I tried using window.parent.location.reload(), but this refreshes the page completely. Is there a way to connect back to the parent without having to refresh the parent? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Here is some pseudo code:        if( window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed ) {
            window.parent.dostuff();
        } else {
     window.parent.dostuff();        
 } The first if works fine, but the moment I refresh the iframe, I cannot call the parent javascript anymore. I can call reload but this refreshes the parent.